# Unable to grep the result count

Tags: unix, grep, find

I'm trying to find the specific type of files and grep the string "COMPLETED KO" and if the count is greater than 0 then it'll send the lines containg the string through mail.

Below is the script:

```
  #!/bin/ksh

cd /home/scripts/log

FILES=`find . -type f -name "TOKEN*" -mtime 1`
ML="ABC@xyz.com"
cd $DIR

err_KO=`grep "ERROR" $FILES |wc -l` 
err_ko=`grep "ERROR" $FILES` > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $err_KO -gt 0 ]
then
echo "error in the files due to KO $err_ko" |mailx -s "KO errors" -r "abcd@xyz.com" $ML
exit 0
fi
```

But on running the script, I'm not getting the required result.

Logs:

```
grep: ./LOG_EQUENS/TOKEN_EQUENS_STOPDEUT_0005000000087916_20171010160102.log: No such file or directory
grep: ./LOG_EQUENS/TOKEN_EQUENS_LOGVODAF_00050000000879D0_20171011061846.log: No such file or directory
grep: ./LOG_SETEFI/TOKEN_SETEFI_SETOVFPM_0005000000087938_20171011011816.log: No such file or directory
grep: ./LOG_SETEFI/TOKEN_SETEFI_SETALMON_00050000000879A6_20171011035809.log: No such file or directory
grep: ./LOG_SETEFI/TOKEN_SETEFI_SETATROA_00050000000879B4_20171011043340.log: No such file or directory
grep: ./LOG_SETEFI/TOKEN_SETEFI_SETSOROA_00050000000879B6_20171011043345.log: No such file or directory
```

Any help is most welcome

Comment: What's the value of `$DIR`? I think you don't want to `cd $DIR`

Comment: I'm assuming there are more than one files in the $FILES variable. You should use a loop to grep line by line so that all the files are looked into. Also, the $DIR looks to be not defined.

Comment: yes, cd $DIR is useless...forgot to remove it

Comment: @mathB : can you please elaborate?

Comment: Oh wait, I understood the logic wrong. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Could you change your find command like this and try? FILES=`find /home/scripts/log/ -type f -name "TOKEN*" -mtime 1`

Comment: is there some issue with mailx ???    `mailx: invalid option -- r
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]`